# Delete duplicate entries when attribute value meets certain requirements and is not blank or space

Tags: powershell, txt

I'm looking at deleting duplicates (rows) from a large TEXT file with header column fields that are separated by tab but only when VATRegistration is not SPACE and VATRegistration only appears again for GroupID 2000 when already existing for one or multiple entries in GroupID 1000.

Input file

```
Supplier    GroupID Name1   City    VATRegistration   Region
9032512 1000    PENRITH PERFORMING AND VISUAL ARTS  Penrith 97003605089 NSW
9032923 1000    TORONTO MULTI PURPOSE CENTRE INC    Toronto 85659352794 NSW
9035991 1000    SYDNEY'S BEST MAINTENANCE AND CLEAN Panania     NSW
9044080 1000    FIRST PEOPLES DISABILITY NETWORK Sydney 58169154330 NSW
9044292 1000    PUNCHY DIGITAL MEDIA PTY LTD    South Melbourne 22166978669 VIC
9044691 1000    POLARON LANGUAGE SERVICES PTY LTD   St Kilda    99120446362 VIC
9047594 1000    WORKSPACE COMMERCIAL FURNITURE PTY  Rosebery        NSW
9075591 1000    ENGADINE COMMUNITY SERVICES INC Engadine    39108386726 NSW
9067825 1000    MELBOURNE MULTI PURPOSE CENTRE INC    Melboure 85659352794 VIC
9076178 1000    CENTRAL COAST AGEING AND DISABILITY Newcastle West  60874001192 NSW
9076319 1000    YASS SOLDIERS' CLUB LTD Yass    44000988152 NSW
9076370 1000    ARTFUL FOOD CO. PTY LIMITED EMU PLAINS  52600861612 NSW
9078232 1000    WSG AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   NORWOOD SOUTH   76604823430 SA
9078312 1000    CAZNER PTY LTD  Manly   39648003570 NSW
9078463 1000    MILSONS POINT DIGITAL PTY LTD   Milsons Point   88635600681 NSW
9079757 1000    RISK & SECURITY MANAGEMENT PTY LTD  Brisbane    71613136048 QLD
9079793 1000    PETRUSIC, MILOJKA   Seven Hills 86077460484 NSW
8487483 2000    FOTI, STEPHANIE BLACKTOWN   78620350307 NSW
7458490 2000    STAFF CHECK PTY LIMITED Marrickville         NSW
75637   2000    ANDERSON, ALLAN GRAHAM  Gladesville      NSW
362789  2000    STAR TRACK EXPRESS PTY LIMITED  CRONULLA    82104931562 NSW
952678  2000    CALCUTTA GROUP PTY LTD  KATOOMBA    52699520223 NSW
2403417 2000    The trustee for Moore Family Trust  NORWOOD SOUTH   76604823430 SA
94905   2000    MEYER PTY LTD   Manly   39648003570 NSW
426783  2000    DAWSON DIGITAL PTY LTD  Milsons Point   88635600681 NSW
8588214 2000    HOME MANAGEMENT PTY LTD Brisbane    71613136048 QLD
```

Expected output file
(keep all entries with VATRegistration = BLANK and VATRegistration duplictated and when GroupID = 1000 but remove duplicate entries of VATRegistration = NOT BLANK but exisitng again for any entry with GroupID = 2000)

```
Supplier    GroupID Name1   City    VATRegistration   Region
9032512 1000    PENRITH PERFORMING AND VISUAL ARTS  Penrith 97003605089 NSW
9032923 1000    TORONTO MULTI PURPOSE CENTRE INC    Toronto 85659352794 NSW
9035991 1000    SYDNEY'S BEST MAINTENANCE AND CLEAN Panania     NSW
9044080 1000    FIRST PEOPLES DISABILITY NETWORK Sydney 58169154330 NSW
9044292 1000    PUNCHY DIGITAL MEDIA PTY LTD    South Melbourne 22166978669 VIC
9044691 1000    POLARON LANGUAGE SERVICES PTY LTD   St Kilda    99120446362 VIC
9047594 1000    WORKSPACE COMMERCIAL FURNITURE PTY  Rosebery        NSW
9075591 1000    ENGADINE COMMUNITY SERVICES INC Engadine    39108386726 NSW
9067825 1000    MELBOURNE MULTI PURPOSE CENTRE INC    Melboure 85659352794 VIC
9076178 1000    CENTRAL COAST AGEING AND DISABILITY Newcastle West  60874001192 NSW
9076319 1000    YASS SOLDIERS' CLUB LTD Yass    44000988152 NSW
9076370 1000    ARTFUL FOOD CO. PTY LIMITED EMU PLAINS  52600861612 NSW
9078232 1000    WSG AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   NORWOOD SOUTH   76604823430 SA
9078312 1000    CAZNER PTY LTD  Manly   39648003570 NSW
9078463 1000    MILSONS POINT DIGITAL PTY LTD   Milsons Point   88635600681 NSW
9079757 1000    RISK & SECURITY MANAGEMENT PTY LTD  Brisbane    71613136048 QLD
9079793 1000    PETRUSIC, MILOJKA   Seven Hills 86077460484 NSW
8487483 2000    FOTI, STEPHANIE BLACKTOWN   78620350307 NSW
7458490 2000    STAFF CHECK PTY LIMITED Marrickville         NSW
75637   2000    ANDERSON, ALLAN GRAHAM  Gladesville      NSW
362789  2000    STAR TRACK EXPRESS PTY LIMITED  CRONULLA    82104931562 NSW
952678  2000    CALCUTTA GROUP PTY LTD  KATOOMBA    52699520223 NSW
```

I have the following PowerShell script already but it cleans up all duplicate entries even when VATRegistration = BLANK and does not look at GroupID.

```
$OutputTXT = ".\Supplier_deduped.txt"
$Unique = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new() 
Import-Csv .\Supplier_all.txt -Delimiter "`t" |ForEach-Object { 
    if ($Unique.Add($_.VATRegistration))  { $_ }  
} | 
  ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"' } |
        Set-Content $OutputTXT -Encoding Unicode
```

It would already help to know on how I would be able to ignore lines that have an empty VATRegistration from being removed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a week, a lot of reading and research but I figured it out myself. Just thought I share with everyone.

```
#Output file variable
$OutputTXT = "C:\temp\Supplier_all_with_blank_ABN_output.txt"

#Temp file variable
$TempTXT = "C:\temp\Supplier_TXT\Supplier_temp.txt"

#Import file variable
$SupplierAllArray = Import-Csv "C:\temp\Supplier_all_with_blank_ABN_input.txt" -Delimiter "`t"

#Store all entries of Suppliers without an ABN in array SupplierABN_blank
$SupplierABN_blank = $SupplierAllArray | Where-Object {$_.VATRegistration -eq ''}  

#Store all entries of Suppliers wit an ABN for all ntries in GroupID 1000 in array $SupplierABN_1000
$SupplierABN_1000  = $SupplierAllArray | Where-Object {$_.VATRegistration -ne '' -and $_.GroupID -eq '1000'} 

#Store all entries of Suppliers wit an ABN for all ntries in GroupID 2000 in array $SupplierABN_2000
$SupplierABN_2000  = $SupplierAllArray | Where-Object {$_.VATRegistration -ne '' -and $_.GroupID -eq '2000'}   

#Delete all Suppliers in GroupID where the ABN already exists in GroupID 1000
$SupplierABN_2000_Deduplicated = $SupplierABN_2000 | Where-Object { $_.VATRegistration -notin $SupplierABN_1000.VATRegistration -and $_.VATRegistration -ne ''}

#Combine all suppliers lists into one variable
$SupplierALL_Deduplicated = $SupplierABN_blank + $SupplierABN_1000 + $SupplierABN_2000_Deduplicated

#Write result list into temporary output file
$SupplierALL_Deduplicated | Sort GroupID , Supplier | Export-Csv $TempTXT -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation |
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"'} | Set-Content $TempTXT -Encoding Unicode

#Read temp file and remove double quotes, sort by GroupID and create final output file
Import-Csv $TempTXT -Delimiter "`t" |
  ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"' } |
        Set-Content $OutputTXT -Encoding Unicode

#Delete temp file
Remove-Item $TempTXT
```